# Intellij Refactor Java Code is different from Mac than from Windows even though the same code style schema is used. why?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, reformatting, reformat

I am using macOS 12.2.

The code should look like this, and this is how is reformatted on a windows machine.

```
router.POST().route(
        "/api/randomStuff") // random comment
        .with(RandomClass::getRandomThing);
```

This is how it looks on a Mac machine:

```
router.POST().route(
            "/api/randomStuff") // random comment
        .with(RandomClass::getRandomThing);
```

Mac machine ads a new TAB when a function parameter is set. Why?

Comment: Hello, please create an issue at YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and attach your project settings exported to it. Thank you

Comment: Please follow https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-289630